# Rails, after remote delete of item I get: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to delete an image on click. 
This is in my view

```
<%=form_for @area, url: areas_update_path, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal",:multipart => true} do |f|%>
....
<% @area.area_attachments.each do |a| %>
  <%unless a.image.blank?%>
    <%= link_to delete_area_attachment_path(a), :remote => true, :method => :delete do%>
       <%= image_tag a.image_url(:thumb), class:"delete-image" %>                 
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
....
<% end %>
```

After I click on an image, the image gets deleted, but I get

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

In the first line of the code that I posted (@area I guess)

My delete_area_attachment method in my area_attachments_controller

```
def delete_area_attachment
   @areaAttachment = AreaAttachment.find(params[:id])
   @areaAttachment.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
end
```

I guess the @area variable has to be initialized, but why?
What I am trying to delete is an area_attachment not an area, and I already initialized it, so what does the @area variable has to do with that?

How do I go about it here?

**EDIT:**
my relative routes:

```
#Area Paths
  get '/areas/new', to: 'areas#new', :as => 'areas_new'
  post '/areas/create', to: 'areas#create', :as => 'areas_create'
  get '/areas/:id/destroy', to: 'areas#destroy', :as => 'areas_destroy'
  delete 'delete_area/:id', controller: 'areas', action: 'delete_area'
  get '/areas/:id/edit', to: 'areas#edit', :as => 'areas_edit'
  patch '/areas/:id/update', to: 'areas#update', :as => 'areas_update'

  #Area Attachment Paths

  delete 'delete_area_attachment/:id', controller: 'area_attachments', action: 'delete_area_attachment', :as => 'delete_area_attachment'
```

My areas_controller

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_areas
    before_action :set_area, only: [:edit, :delete, :update, :destroy]


    def new
        @area = Area.new
        @languages = Language.all
        @area_attachment = @area.area_attachments.build
    end

    def create
        @area = Area.new(area_params)

        if @area.save && manage_strings
            params[:area_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @area_attachment = @area.area_attachments.create!(:image => a, :area_id => @area.id)
            end
            @status = 'success'
        else
            @status = 'error'
            @errormessages = @area.errors.full_messages
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def edit        

    end

    def update
        if @area.update(area_params) && manage_strings
            params[:area_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @area_attachment = @area.area_attachments.create!(:image => a, :area_id => @area.id)
            end
            @status = 'success'
        else
            @status = 'error'
            @errormessages = @area.errors.full_messages
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def delete_area
        @area = Area.find(params[:id])
        @area.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def find_area_by_id
        area = Area.find(params[:id])
        render json: area
    end

    protected

    def news_list
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end



    private

    def area_params
      params.require(:area).permit(:id, area_attachments_attributes: [:id, :area_id, :image])
   end

    def set_area
        @area = Area.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @languages = Language.all
        @area_attachments = @area.area_attachments.all
    end

    def set_areas
        @areas = Area.all
    end

    def manage_strings
        if params[:area][:strings].any?
            params[:area][:strings].each do |key,value|
                string = @area.article_localizations.find_or_initialize_by(:language_id => key.to_i)
                string.title = params[:area][:strings][key][:title]
                string.text = params[:area][:strings][key][:text]
                string.save
            end
        end 
    end

end
```

Comment: You got a link inside a form? Very unusual and unnecessary.

Comment: @Pavan Each area has area_attachments and I want to display them all and delete them on click.

Comment: I didn't get why you are using form, since `link_to` will perform what you needed.

Comment: @Pavan this is an edit form for **area**. I thought this is the best way to edit an object, would you suggest something else?

Comment: Ok. Is the file name is `edit.html.erb`? Also please update the question with the controller code.

Comment: @Pavan do you mean areas_controller? I will post right now, but I don't see how this affects the particular problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113523/discussion-between-pavan-and-dyserone).

Comment: What is the path of the view file?

Comment: @Pavan app/views/areas/modals/_editAreaModal.html.erb

Comment: And how and which file this partial is called?

Comment: I create a list with all my areas. Each area has a link_to to generate the content and open _editAreaModal.html.erb. the link_to is:

`<%= link_to areas_edit_path(area), :remote => true,:class => "btn btn-info" do %>Edit<% end %>`

Comment: @Pavan Panos's answer was on point. Thank for helping out anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In delete_area_attachment before `@areaAttachment.destroy` add:

```
@area = Area.find_by_id(@areaAttachment.area_id)
```